# Safely remove folders that only Windows uses

Tags: windows, directory, delete

I've been using an external hard drive in Windows, but now that I decided to switch to Ubuntu, I wonder if I can safely remove the folders `$RECYCLE.bin`, `RECYCLER`, `$AVG` and `found.000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feel free to delete all the folders you mentioned. Ubuntu does not use them, and instead uses [its own recycle folder called ./Trash](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-empty-the-ubuntu-gnome-trash-from-the-command-line/)

**Edit 1**: Expect Microsoft Windows to re-create the recycler-related folders the next time you connect the drive to a windows machine.

Also, the **found.000** folder indicates your hard drive had a problem reading data in the past, which Microsoft scandisk caught and tried to recover. If the data on the drive is important to you, please ensure you have a current backup of that drive.

Thanks to brunopereira81 for mentioning the source of the found.000 folder.

Hope that helps

Comment: Also [it is very difficult to recover data](http://superuser.com/questions/124690/what-can-i-do-with-chk-files-in-found-000-folders) from chk files inside found.00x folders.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I'm cleaning that drive and making a backup of my data

Answer (score 2):

Yes, unless you use your recycle bin as a quick archive for your files (had a friend that did that... "I press delete and all my files are quickly saved under the same place, find a program that does the same and I will stop using the recycle as my archive!") ;)

The 2 first ones are recycle bin related, AVG probably is your quarantine folder for AVG and found.000 is a trace from a scandisk you ran.

If you are not planning to use windows again it is safe to delete those folders.

Comment: You cannot interact with folders inside Recycle Bin in windows. How exactly did getting all stuff in same place help your friend?

Comment: :) when he needed to "quick save" a file he pressed delete and file was sent to recycle bin. When he wanted it back he opened the recycle bin selected the file>cut>paste to the new location he wanted. You can interact with them, you have 3 options right clicking on a file inside recycle bin: restore, cut and delete.

Comment: Actually you can access this folder in windows, showing hidden and system files

Comment: @ConeJoXM idd, but its a very very bad place to save files on :P Welcome to askubuntu!